# Windows 8.1 Bluetooth mouse jitter with Wifi on

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, bluetooth, lag

I'm facing some weird mouse behavior with my Bluetooth mouse on a PC running Windows 8.1.

The problem is that the mouse will periodically begin to "jitter" for some time and then stop again.. And by "jitter" i mean lag and input is delayed. Its like its working fine for 100ms and then it stops completely for another 300ms, and then runs again for 100ms and so fourth..

The weird part is that, if i turn WiFi off via the taskbar, the mouse does not jitter at all. I've updated all my drivers and windows has been completely updated.

Does anyone here know what could possible be wrong? Is there some setting i need to change somewhere?

Comment: It’s not strange at all. WiFi and Bluetooth are known to interfere with each other. The frequency ranges they use overlap.

Comment: I had thoughted about that. Both running 2.4Ghz right? Is there some way i can "fix" this so that i can run both wifi and bluetooth without them interfering?